# Java Web Font Characters not recognized

Tags: java

in java i want to create enum contains all material design icons icons but some icon chars can't accepted in java like

```
ACCOUNT_EDIT_OUTLINE('\uF001D'),
```

how write correct character name?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `F001D` and not `F01D`?  Most icon fonts start their characters at F000, which is in the [BMP Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

Comment: the value **F001D** from font CSS file that contain all characters Unicode values

Comment: Please show us that line in the font CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed by  replacing char in enum by using string
ACCOUNT_EDIT_OUTLINE("F001D")
And convert the string to char befor use it